# Eliminando valores repetidos de um vetor

Tags: c++11

Olá, pessoal resumidamente o meu problema é eliminar valores repetidos de um vetor, aqui está meu código e logo abaixo uma breve explicação.

=========================================================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int* unique( int *first, int *last);
int main(){

int A[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5 };

//aplicar unique sobre A.

auto last = unique(std::begin(A), std::end(A));

//o comando abaixo deveria imprimir A com o conteudo 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
for( auto i = std::begin(A); i != last; ++i){
    std::cout << *i << " ";
}

std::cout << endl;

//mostrar o novo tamanho de A, que seria 5.
std:: cout << ">>O comprimento logico de A apos o unique() eh: " << std::distance(std::begin(A), last) << std::endl;
std::cout << ">>O retorno indica a posição do elemento: " <<*last << std::endl;


    return 0;
}


int* unique( int *first, int *last){
auto slow = first+2;
    for (auto fast = first+2; fast != last; ++fast){
        for (auto i = slow; i != first; /*empty*/){
            if(*fast != *i ){
                swap(*slow++, *fast);
            }
            --i;
        }
    }
    return slow;
}
```

=========================================================================

Bem, basicamente eu mando dois ponteiros indicando o inicio e o final do meu vetor, em seguida crio mais dois ponteiros (slow e fast), o fast percorre o vetor e testa se o elemento atual é diferente do que esta atrás do slow, fazendo com que empurre os valores repetidos pro final do vetor e ficando apenas os valores únicos no inicio, a função retorna slow, ou seja, indica onde termina os valores unicos, o problema surge exatamente nessa parte de testar do slow pra tras, a função não esta me retornando o valor exato, queria fazer esse teste usando a função swap().

Comment: Coloque o código em texto pra facilitar pra gente. E diga o objetivo final, porque é possível que outro algoritmo seja melhor que este.

Comment: obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Por que você pula 2 no começo?